# Deco M5 wifi mesh bandwidth management

Tags: wireless-networking, mesh-networking

I'm looking for a solution on how to monitor & manage my TP-LINK Deco M5 mesh network. The provided deco app is very limited, esp. when it comes to bandwidth. There's a QoS which allows you to set a few rules and that's it. AFAICT it's not possible to install networking tools on the deco router itself, i.e. this would mean that I need to install some kind of network manager on each device? Or am I overlooking an other simple solution here? Basically I just want to be able to make sure that when someone starts downloading something it doesn't clog the entire network.

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking too much  from a consumer grade network equipement which does already a lot for the price.

Maybe you should look into more "sophisticated" devices like the EAP line at TP Link with the Omada Controler or Ubiquiti.